# How to save link slices photoshop file as only HTML file or only one JPEG/PNG but link should work?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I design an email signature in Photoshop. And linked with my facebook and linkedin page via slice tool. I want to use this on Outlook. But when I try to export this by "Save for Web" it shows 3 options 1. "HTML and Images 2. Images only and 3. HTML only.

Note: 1. When I use "HTML and Images" then photoshop exports it's as a HTML file with "Images" folder but linked work.
2. When I use "Images only" then photoshop will exports it's as one png/jpeg file but linked not working.
3. When I save this as "HTML only" then link work but I didn't see anything on my browser. It just black

I want this either one HTML without images or one jpeg/png but facebook and linkedin link must work.

How do I do that?

Comment: Hi Jason, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is an *image map*.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_map

While you can't literally create ONE image with multiple links, you CAN slice up an image into smaller parts which then can be referred to as independent elements of an HTML layout.

There are free online tools for generating image maps.

http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/

Unfortunately, Outlook 2010 does not allow image mapping. You'd be better off creating separate images and linking each individually.